# SFML - Cannot modify object in window

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I am new to SFML and C++ in general.
I am building the Conway's Game of life for a school project.

As base objects for my grid, I have Squares (which are `sf::RectangleShape` as for base).
The grid is a `std::vector<std::vector<Square>>` (vector of vectors of Squares).

What I am trying to do at the moment is to change the color of a square when I hover over it with the cursor.
My way of doing it (see code below):

1. I get the position of cursor when I move it
2. I iterate through my matrix and check for each square if cursor's position is in the square's boundaries.
3. When the square under the cursor is found, I want to change its color (`.setFillColor(...)`).

**Point 3 does not work I can't understand why. This is the function "mouseHover" in the code below.**
Can you see what is wrong?

```
int main()
{
    int width;
    int height;
    int numberSquareWidth = 15;
    int numberSquareHeight = 15;
    int squareSize = 20;
    int offset = 1;
    initializeWindowGridValues(width, height, numberSquareWidth, numberSquareHeight, squareSize, offset);

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Stephan's Game Of Life!");
    std::vector<std::vector<Square>> matrix(numberSquareWidth, std::vector<Square>(numberSquareHeight));
    initiatlizeGrid(numberSquareWidth, numberSquareHeight, squareSize, offset, matrix);

    sf::Vector2i cursorPos;
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();

            if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseMoved)
            {
                cursorPos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
            }
        }
        mouseHover(matrix, cursorPos, squareSize, offset); // Problem here

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        drawGrid(window, matrix);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}

void mouseHover(std::vector<std::vector<Square>> &matrix, const sf::Vector2i &cursorPos, const int &squareSize, const int &offset)
{
    int rowIndex = floor((cursorPos.x - (offset * floor(cursorPos.x / squareSize))) / squareSize);
    int colIndex = floor((cursorPos.y - (offset * floor(cursorPos.y / squareSize))) / squareSize);
    matrix[rowIndex][colIndex].setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue); // This does not happen.
}

void drawGrid(sf::RenderWindow &window, const std::vector<std::vector<Square>> &matrix)
{
    for (const auto &vector : matrix)
    {
        for (const auto &square : vector)
        {
            window.draw(square);
        }
    }
}

void initiatlizeGrid(const int &numberSquareWidth, const int &numberSquareHeight, const int &squareSize, const int &offset, std::vector<std::vector<Square>> &matrix)
{
    int previousY = 0;
    for (size_t row = 0; row < numberSquareWidth; row++)
    {
        int offsetv;
        if (row == 0)
        {
            offsetv = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            offsetv = offset;
        }
        int previousX = 0;
        for (size_t col = 0; col < numberSquareHeight; col++)
        {
            int offseth;
            if (col == 0)
            {
                offseth = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                offseth = offset;
            }
            Square square(squareSize);
            square.setPosition(previousX + offseth, previousY + offsetv);
            matrix[row][col] = square;
            previousX = previousX + squareSize + offseth;
        }
        previousY = previousY + squareSize + offsetv;
    }
}

void initializeWindowGridValues(int &width, int &height, int &nuberSquareWidth, int &nuberSquareHeight, int &squareSize, const int &offset)
{
    if (nuberSquareWidth * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareWidth - 1) > 1800 || nuberSquareHeight * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareHeight - 1) > 900)
    {
        nuberSquareWidth = floor(1600 / squareSize);
        nuberSquareHeight = floor(900 / squareSize);
        width = ceil(nuberSquareWidth * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareWidth - 1));
        height = ceil(nuberSquareHeight * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareHeight - 1));
    }
    else if (nuberSquareWidth < 5 || nuberSquareHeight < 5)
    {
        nuberSquareWidth = 5;
        nuberSquareHeight = 5;
        width = ceil(nuberSquareWidth * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareWidth - 1));
        height = ceil(nuberSquareHeight * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareHeight - 1));
    }
    else
    {
        width = ceil(nuberSquareWidth * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareWidth - 1));
        height = ceil(nuberSquareHeight * squareSize + offset * (nuberSquareHeight - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: the collision logic works on me, can you show initializegrid() and initializeWindowGridValues()

Comment: @LorenceHernandez I added my whole main(). Note that I change the implementation of `mouseover()`: I calculate the indexes of the square in the matrix instead of iterating over the vectors. `initializeWindowGridValues()` makes sure that the window will be big enough to display all the grid and sets max and min size for it in case of extreme values. `initializegrid()` populates my vector of vectors of squares with squares with appropriate position values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have both inherited the `RectangleShape` (my square IS A RectangleShape) and made a `RectangleShape` (square) a member of myclass. When I modify data, I modify class member variables, but inside the draw method I draw the other rectangle.

I removed the class member `RectangleShape` and continue from here.